# Python time gives wrong value

Tags: python-3.x, epoch

I'm trying to convert an epoch time to string in python. But I'm getting wrong year. While the same number is converted by 'epoch converter' with ease.

```
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(1529587632523))
'50440-09-13 13:28:43'
```

[image]

Comment: Well if you take a look here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html#time.gmtime it clearly states that the time should be in secs, while on the webpage it is in miliseconds. You should firstly check the documentation if unsure in such cases.

Comment: @Sqoshu I'm not trying to be rude here. But you have to understand. When I searched for converting epoch to localtime, I get a lot of results. The issue is I don't know which one is correct, which is why I asked the question. If I knew that this is the correct function, I would have checked it in documentation closely. Otherwise, it is difficult to go through every function in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the epoch time is in milli seconds and I have to divide by 1000 to get to convert.

```
import time
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(msg.timestamp/1000)))
```